# Cocoapods "Framework not found Pods_<my_project_name>"

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am trying to set up Cocoapods with my project for the first time, to use one framework that only comes as a pod. I already have an `xcworkspace` file, so I specified that in the `Podfile`. When I run `pod install`, it adds a reference to a framework `Pods_<my_project_name>`, but Xcode can't find that framework at build time. I can't find it on disk either. I see the framework for my one included pod framework in the `Pods` directory, but no `Pods_<my_project>.framework`.

If I delete the reference to the errant framework I can build, but it comes back if I run `pod install` again.

My issue is very similar to [this reported issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6578), but I am definitely opening and building via my `xcworkspace` file.

When I first ran `pod install` it warned about some things, like including a reference to their `xcconfig` file in mine and setting `$(inherited)` in some settings I had values for - I fixed all those, and `pod install` no longer produces any warnings.

What is this framework supposed to be / do? Where is it supposed to live?

EDIT: Here's the Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '12.0'
workspace 'iOS'

target "MyProject" do
    use_frameworks!
    pod 'AdaptiveCards', '1.2.7'
end
```

Comment: Sharing the `Podfile` might help to diagnose.

Comment: @PaulBeusterien added.